# What the difference in vim, compiled with python (ruby) support and without it?

Tags: vim

I want to use vim on many servers, where in repository it compiled without ruby and python support. But syntax plugins work fine on it. And other things looks normal, when i trying to edit python file.

I will use it with plenty of filetypes (configs, logs, sourcecode and other), and i want to know the difference and decide to use repository's version or compiled by myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The optional Python, Ruby, Perl or Scheme supports allow script developers to write vim plugins in their chosen languages. Vim will, when compiled in, provide a small interface for interacting. It doesn't affect the syntax files or indentations etc. They are written in VimScript.

There are quite a few nontrivial Vim plugins that use Python so at least compiling Vim with Python support will expand your options with plugins in noticeable manner.

Answer (score 0):

When not compiled with `+python`, Vim is not able to perform omnicompletion for python code. I believe it's the same for Ruby.